# How to generate a generic CriteriaQuery with foreign key property?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Example entities:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="EMP_ID")
    private long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
    private List<Phone> phones;
    ...
}
@Entity
public class Phone {
    @Id
    private long id;    
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID")
    private Employee owner;
    ...
}
```

I have a generic class where queries are generated based on the type of the entity:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    private Class<T> type;

    public List<T> select(String property, Object value) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> q = cb.createQuery(type);
        Root<T> root = q.from(type);
        Path<Object> path = root.get(property);
        query.where(path.in(value));
        query.select(q.select(root));
        TypedQuery<A> query = em.createQuery(q);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

I want to generate the following query

```
SELECT * FROM PHONE WHERE OWNER_ID = ?
```

by executing

```
Repository<Phone> repository;
List<Phone> phones = repository.select("owner.id", 1);
```

but it doesn't work, because "owner.id" can't be found. Though the statement

```
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Phone p WHERE p.owner.id = :id")
```

is actually working.

How can i create a generic CriteriaQuery based on type `T` resulting in the specified statement without knowing the type of `Employee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split your `property` and then join `Employee`. For one level of join it could look like this:

```
 String[] splitProperty = property.split(".");
 Join<Object, Object> owner = root.join(splitProperty[0]);
 Path<Object> path = owner.get(splitProperty[1]);
 q.where(path.in(value));
 ...
```

Of course if you want more generic solution you have to iterate over the split parts and join other tables.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm gonna implement this as suggested in a loop to support multiple joins.

Answer (score 1):

You can join to the Parent (`Employee`) from the Child entity (`Phone`) and ask the joned entity for its `id` property.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Child> cq = cb.createQuery(Child.class);
Root<Child> cr = cq.from(Child.class);
Join<Child, Parent> pj = cr.join("parent");
cq.where(cb.equal(pj.get("id"), 1));
List<Child> rl = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
System.out.println(rl);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this example i need to know the type of `Child`, but my generic class just knows the type of the parent.